# Which mobile device emulators do you use to test mobile development?

Tags: javascript, android, iphone, ipad, mobile

I was wondering what emulators everyone uses to test your mobile development, want to make sure I'm using the most accurate emulators/simulators.

I currently use the Electric Mobile Simulator from electric plum for iPad and iPhone simulation as well as Opera Mini and Mobile emulators. I have downloaded the Android SDK but have trouble making this work so am very dubious about the results I see on this.

I understand that using a real device to test my pages will merit the best results but Id also likes to have a decent emulator pack on my desktop just to give me a rough guide of how the development process is progressing.

All suggestions and feedback welcomed

Kyle

Comment: The best testing is with a real device, emulators can only do so much, many a time I've had flawless results on a simulator, ten seconds on a device and things go wrong.
I find the xcode simulator is as good as any, im sure others will have preferences

Comment: If you only want to test device compatibility, the best way is to test it on a real device, if you want to know more abou user experience try [heatma.ps](https://heatma.ps)

Comment: See this question for some ideas [enter link description here][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7564702/iphone-and-android-simulators-for-mobile-web-development/7565401#7565401

Answer (score 2):

Get as many real devices as possible. Then, to ease the pain for mobile web development, hack something together like Shim: https://github.com/marstall/shim to coordinate all your browsing.

Answer (score 1):

I use [Opera Mobile Emulator](http://www.opera.com/developer/tools/mobile/) with Opera Dragonfly as a debugging tool, which makes styling and scripting pretty easy 90% of the way. If running Opera (Mobile & Mini), you can connect your **real devices** to the developer tools window of Dragonfly - that's a great way to effectively scan your code.

The current commercial version of [Electric Mobile Simulator](http://www.electricplum.com/dlsim.html) states to render just as iOS. It actually comes very close. It basically is a Chrome fork - which works, because both Chrome and Safari are *Webkit browsers*. However, rendering pages that use flash fallbacks and other trickery might display differently on the simulator. *EMS* has built-in developer tools, which helps a lot finding those crummy css bugs. I use this tool a lot.

There *was* a free version of *Electric Mobile Simulator*, however it rendered most of the content equating to the operating system's browser (Can't find the version now however).

Android SDK is a giant. I used it before, and I doubt that it can offer you anything you couldn't achieve with Opera Mobile Emulator or Electric MS. It can be sluggish, slow responding - depending on the performance of your machine. However, simulating a device in Android SDK brings you very close to the real deal.

But in the end, you **definitely** need to test on real devices. Not all bugs show in simulators, also you can't precisely simulate touch events. We started collecting used mobile devices (iPhone3, iPad1, older Samsung models and so on); and will continue doing so.

**Summary:** Nothing replaces testing mobile sites on real devices, but emulators can speed up development from the project's start until the middle of beta stage.

Answer (score 0):

You could also use DeviceAnywhere. With DA you test on real devices.